# Why the child process won't execute in this code?

Tags: c, fork

The child process is skiped, idk why... I used debugger and it doesn't give any clues why...only runs trhough the code ending with the printf of the parent process... Thanks in advance. Don't know what to say more my first time asking a question, it's asking me for details ... But I don't know what else to say, the purpose of the code is to run the "verificador" program which is a program that verifies in a given string how many forbidden words exist, so I've tried this, where my "server" would communicate through a pipe with "verificador" and than save the number of forbidden words to give to the "client".

```
#include <sys/errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void myabort(const char * msg, int exit_status){
    perror(msg);
    exit(exit_status);
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;
    int fd[2],newfd,nbytes;
    int status;
    char word[]="filipe";
    FILE* f;

    if(pipe(fd)<0) myabort("unable to create unamed pipe",-1);

    switch(pid=fork()){
        case -1: // Error
                myabort("Unable to fork()",-3);
                break;

        case  0:
            printf("CHILD PROCESS");
            if(close(fd[0])==-1) myabort ("CHILD: Error while closing the read end of the pipe.",-4);
            if(close(STDOUT_FILENO)==-1) myabort ("CHILD: Error while closing the standard output.",-4);
            if(dup(fd[1])==-1) myabort("CHILD: Error while duplicating the pipe write end",-5);
            if(close(fd[1])==-1) myabort ("CHILD: Error while closing the original write end descriptor of the pipe.",-4);
            //fprintf(stdout, "%s", word);
            write(1,word,sizeof(word));
            break;

        default:
            printf("PARENT PROCESS");
            wait(&status);
            close(STDIN_FILENO);
            newfd = dup(fd[0]);
            close(fd[0]);
            close(fd[1]);

            f = fdopen(newfd, "r");
            if(f == NULL) myabort("Error opening new file descriptor.", -1);

            execl("verificador", "verificador", "palavras_proibidas", NULL);

            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: _The child process is skiped, idk why ?_ Child process runs, you may not see the `printf()` output on your console due to the fact that its buffered IO. You need to use `'\n` to flush the buffer or use `fflush()`. Try `printf("CHILD PROCESS\n");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is as follows:

Here, you write a string to the stdout stream:

```
printf("CHILD PROCESS");
```

This output is buffered, due to line buffering when stdout is a terminal.
Usually, this buffer is implicitly flushed when the program ends, showing the output. But here:

```
if(close(STDOUT_FILENO)==-1) myabort ("CHILD: Error while closing the standard output.",-4);
if(dup(fd[1])==-1) myabort("CHILD: Error while duplicating the pipe write end",-5);
```

you *close* the stdout filedescriptor (1), which was connected to your terminal, and connect it to your pipe. So, when the stdout-stream is (implicitly or explicitly) flushed after this, the output goes to the pipe!

You have to make sure, that the output is flushed before closing the filedescriptor, to not only make sure, that it is printed to the terminal, but also to not corrupt the communication through the pipe with your verificator-process. Because, as it stands, your verificator process will receive the string

```
"filipe\0CHILD PROCESS"
```

when the stdout stream is implicitly flushed when your child process ends (i.e. returns from `main()`)

The easiest and safest way to fix this situation is to call

```
fflush(stdout);
```

directly before you close filedescriptor 1.

Comment: First of all, thanks, 2nd can you see the edit ? For some reason I can't still run the program I want in fork...

Answer (score -1):

It does run. This is a problem with buffered streams. They may have the need to be flushed.

One solution is to add a newline character:

```
printf("CHILD PROCESS\n");
```

Adding a newline character will work in most situations, since many terminals do an automatic flush when encountering a newline. But you can also be more specific:

```
printf("CHILD PROCESS");
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: It works, any idea why the execl isnt executing, i mean the "verificador" should be working now right?

Comment: @MrSano43 How do you know it is not executing? You're not checking the return value at all.

Comment: The verificador program receive the word from stdin and then it should be running after the exec no?

Comment: @MrSano43 I have absolutely no way of continuing the debugging since I don't have that file on my computer.

Comment: Added the "verificador" code , check it if you can, thanks in advance.

Comment: @MrSano43 It does not work that way. Now we have figured out that the child process indeed runs. SO is not for iterative solutions. It's made for good QA-pairs. After you got this solved you should spend at least half a day trying to debug it with your new knowledge and then - if you fail - create a NEW question with a [mre]. Don't change questions. It invalidates answers. I have rolled back your edit.

Comment: What you are supposed to do now is follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and upvote and accept answers.

Comment: Sorry was just because it was intended that the child processo would execute the program, and it wasnt that much new information as you're saying,  but I got it running, thanks.